# Why does python change all instances of a class upon changing one single instance?

Tags: python, class, attributes

In the following python script I initialize attribute v of two instances of a class (tt1 and tt2) with the same array s. Then I apply the method "add" to only one of the instances, changing attribute v. However, v is changed not only for tt1, but also for tt2. Moreover, s is also changed. If s is defined as a scalar value instead of an array (and method add() changed accordingly), attribute v is changed only for tt1. Why is this? Many thanks for your feedback.

Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([1,2,3])

class test_class:

    def __init__(self,vv):
        self.v = vv
        
    def add(self,h,i):
        aux = self.v
        aux[i] += h
        self.v = aux
        
tt1=test_class(s)
tt2=test_class(s)

tt1.add(1,0)

print('s = ', s)
print('tt1.v = ',tt1.v)
print('tt2.v = ',tt2.v)
```

This is the output:

```
s =  [2 2 3]
tt1.v =  [2 2 3]
tt2.v =  [2 2 3]
```

Comment: You have multiple references to only one numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using the reference but the address to data structure is same list you have intialized at first try using deepcopy which creates another list and you can work independently.

Comment: Many thanks, deepcopy solves the problem. What I still don't understand is why in my original code s remains unchanged by the method add() if I define it as a scalar value instead of a numpy array at the beginning?

Comment: welcome and for your confusion ::        in python generally the reference is bind with the object in case of list         you have changed the list itself                                     
       but in case of scalar value you have changed just the pointer value  where acutal object remains unchangeable